# Printing PDF file created with LuaLaTeX is missing characters

Tags: fonts, pdf, characters, printing, pdfx

I have typeset my document with LuaLaTeX. The PDF output file (PDF/A-1b format created using the pdfx package) looks fine; all characters and font types / styles are displayed correctly. The PDF reader says that the fonts/styles being used are embedded as a subset:

[image: Embedded Fonts]

But when I print the PDF, some (!) characters are not printed. This goes for the letters "ß" (if bold) and "ü" (if bold-italic). Even though other umlauts (e.g. "Ä" (bold-italic), "ä" (bold-italic), even "ü" (bold)) are being printed without any problem:

[image: Missing ü if bold-italic]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @Bobyandbob That's not a sensible MWE for lualatex.

Comment: And provide a log-file.

Comment: If it's o.k. in the viewer but broken in print, it's probably a printer issue.